# Boolean modifier makes a hole without rim in render

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to add a boolean modifier to the face of a character to animate the face. It seems to work in the view port, but when I render it I lose the rim around the mouth/eyes.

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your normals are probably inverted, in edit mode press Ctrl N to make all normals consistent. Another part of the the problem is that some of your modifiers are disabled for preview (the eye icon) and then are enabled for the render (camera icon), so you will have a discrepancy between the viewport and the render. Is there also some geometry that is disabled for preview but that is being rendered? Please update your question with more information or make the file available for others to inspect.

Comment: Enabling the other modifiers makes no difference. I tried Ctrl-N but it did not change anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Geometry is there, it is a matter of your materials and lights. The light inside is so strong that you cannot see anything. Hide it and you see the rim.